Grease Won't Go through Zerk Fittings
I'm trying to grease the idler arm and idler arm bracket made by Precision. But when I squeeze the gun, grease oozes out of the end of the hose instead of going into the zerk fitting for neither the idler arm or idler arm bracket. I used this gun recently on tie rods and I was able to do everything fine. I took off the zerk fitting off of the idler arm bracket and put it directly on the end of the hose on the grease gun, and I was able to have grease come directly through the zerk fitting by itself just fine, so that means the zerk fitting is not clogged. But when I put the zerk fitting back on the idler arm bracket, the problem still persists leaving me thinking "Wut?". I have no idea what's wrong, this should be very simple.
Edit: I need to add another detail to this. The idler arm bracket comes with a hose with a zerk fitting at the end so you can attach it to the part to grease the part through the hose. My problem is grease won't go through the hose into the idler arm bracket.

I'm wondering if the manufacturer just put them on there to make the owner "feel good" with the idea the owner would never actually grease them. Wouldn't be the first time for something like that.

For the idler arm, it turns out I was using a wrong size zerk fitting. I must have mixed up the zerk fittings from different parts packages. Problem solved there.
For the hose, there is grease in the hose but when I put a straight mini pick down the hose, there was a blockage. So I jammed the straight mini pick further into the hose with a mallet and when the mini pick was as deep as it could go, I tried it again with the grease gun. Grease slowly went out of the other end and blockage seemed to dissapear with each squeeze of the gun. I think the hose was partialy collapsed and needed to be opened up.
